# Understanding SOLID and KISS principles through java

Tags: java, design-patterns

could any one provide examples or any links of basics of *SOLID* and *KISS* principles using plain/core Java. I extensively tried going through different websites including the wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) and https://dzone.com/articles/the-solid-principles-in-real-life but was never able to cross after S.and O. part of the SOLID.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Did you try your search engine? Mine is very generous when for example I type “Liskov substitution principle Java example”.